# Spring test mockmvc get request with body

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

From my understanding when Request Method is Get we should not have Request body, we use `@RequestParam` to read the url parameters. But spring test seems to be allowing it. Below is a sample code.

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(@RequestBody Student student) {
        return "Hello "+ student.name;
    }

}
```

This is the test code and `jsonString` is the string representation of a `Student` object.

```
@Test
    public void shouldReturnMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/abc").content(jsonString)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

My question here is, should Spring stop allowing `@RequestBody` with `Get` request? The above test runs fine and it's able to return me the student name. But when I try to call the same endpoint using curl it throws an error.

Reference : [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Any HTTP request can have a body, so no.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages

Comment: Actually this doubt came into my mind when I was trying to access the same endpoint with my ReactJs application and axios. I tried to pass the body and it's was not getting passed from the browser. So, my immediate concern was how the spring -test passed. From what I understand going through this [Link](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787) is that `XHR` does not allow. But, seems like Spring allows which seems odd. You can take a look at the same link you shared [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)